# FileStorage OpenCV

Tags: opencv, file-storage

I am trying to save Camera matrix and distortion co efficients for later use but, the code I have written does not seem to work. It is not storing any kind of data on the yml file. Even when I read it back, it does not does not input anything to the specified matrices. 
Please help me understand if I am doing something wrong. 
I am using VS2010 with OpenCV 2.4.5

```
    cv::Mat CameraMatrix, DistCoeffs;
    CameraMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    DistCoeffs = (cv::Mat_<double>(1,5) << 10, 11, 12, 13, 15);
    cv::FileStorage fs("IntCali.yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "CameraMatrix" << CameraMatrix;
    fs << "DistCoeffs" << DistCoeffs;
    fs.release();

    cv::FileStorage fs2("IntCali.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
    cv::Mat cm; fs2["CameraMatrix"] >> cm;
    cv::Mat dc;
    fs2["DistCoeffs"] >> dc;
        fs2.release();
```

Comment: please provide your errors.

Comment: A quick way to output OpenCV Mat is to do this: cout << CameraMatrix << endl; Do this for your CameraMatrix and DistCoeffs before writing them to the file to check that they are initialized properly. Do the same to check that they are read back properly. Your code appears correct at a glance...

Comment: Btw you can open the IntCali.yml file to check its content. It is just a text file.

Comment: I have no errors displayed in the output window but, there is no data that is stored in the .yml file. It is empty. I also checked by using cout. The CameraMatrix and DistCoeffs exist but cm and dc do not.

Comment: weird. works perfectly on 2.4.2 and 2.4.9(master)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<opencv_storage>
-<CameraMatrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>3</rows>
<cols>3</cols>
<dt>d</dt>
<data> 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.</data>

</CameraMatrix>-<DistCoeffs type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>1</rows>
<cols>5</cols>
<dt>d</dt>
<data> 10. 11. 12. 13. 15.</data>
</DistCoeffs>
</opencv_storage>
```

Works in xml file. If there is no special requirement for yml file only, try xml.

Comment: Or yaml, which is ok too.